# how to reload the component in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

shared.service.ts

```
    public _test:any;

      set test(value:any) {
        this._test = value
      }

      get test():any {
        return this._test;
      }
```

header.ts

```
 private postValues() {
    this._PartService.PostDataValues(this.search).subscribe(
      result => {
         this.sharedService._test
        })
  }

  onSearch() {
       this.postValues()
   }
```

home.ts

```
private downloadRecentSearches() {
   this.recentSearchService.download().subscribe(
    searches => {
      this.resultData = searches;
      this.originalSearches = this.resultData.data;
      this.sharedService._test = this.originalSearches
      this.onSelectItem()
    })
  }
```

In the code above, I am setting the result in "this.sharedService._test" and in header component on click of search I am saving the new result search and that result has to update in home component 
  so I am not getting how to go back to home component and get the new result search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use angular's `EventEmitter`. When the user click trigger onsearch you can send an event to other components together with `this.search` value inputted by the user. And in your home component.ts you can listen to the event and check if it returns a data (which is the search value) then you can call `downloadRecentSearches()` and you pass the value returned by the event.

for more info about component interaction in angular you can check their documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

example:

> shared.service.ts

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() search: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

searchChanged(value) {
   this.search.emit(value);
}
```

> search.component.ts

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('change')
onSearch() {
   this.sharedService.searchChanged(this.search)
}
```

> home.component.ts

```
constructor() {
  this.eventListener();
}

eventListener() {
   this.sharedService.search.subscribe((searchValue) => {
       console.log(searchValue) // value of the inputted by user
       // do your logic here
   })
}
```

Comment: It has no child to parent relationship, so how can I use EventEmitter here